# Delphi Tokyo IOS App Development for arm64e

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, delphi-10.2-tokyo, paserver

I was wondering if anyone can give me a definitive answer on this.  I have been battling for weeks now to build a small, simple app for personal use on my iPhone. I have managed to get it to work on my iPhone 6S, but I cannot get it onto my iPhone XR.

I am using Delphi 10.2.3 and PAServer 19.  I also have access to XCode 9, 10 and 11 on a MAC.

I can successfully build and run my app on my iPhone 6S using SDK 9.3, but it won't build and run on my iPhone XR.  Conversely, if I try to use XCode 10 or 11, I get linker errors and it basically won't work.

Is there any way I can get my app onto my iPhone XR with the setup I have, or would my only option be to upgrade to Delphi Rio?

Answer (score 0):

I'm impressed that you figured out how to target more than one version of XCode. I could not. I have always had to completely remove one XCode to use another.

That leads me to wonder whether you are correctly targeting XCode 10 or 11 with the appropriate SDK, especially if you are seeing linker errors.